# アセンブリ署名を行ったexeファイルを判別したい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

VCS2015にて、アセンブリ署名を施したexeファイルを候補の中の全exeファイルから
抽出したいのですが、その方法を教えてください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「候補の中の全exeファイルから抽出」は質問に必要な内容でしょうか？ １ファイル判定できれば、後は質問者さんが適切にループすれば済む話に感じます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static byte[] GetPublicKeyToken(string fullpath) {
    return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fullpath).GetName().GetPublicKey();
}
```

でアセンブリ署名に使用された公開鍵を取得できます。この値を比較してください。ただし.NETアセンブリでない場合は例外が発生します。

Comment: すみません、いつもありがとうございます。
前回のご指摘の末、アセンブリ著名で識別する方法に決めたのですが、
今一つやり方が解りませんでした。
ひとつ取得できてしまえば、まぁ後はループで大丈夫なのは解るのですが…。
質問文に不足があった点、お許しください。